The instance of entity type {ModelName} cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked
I got this error when trying to seed data to the database

"The instance of entity type 'Unit' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'UnitId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attach..."

This is the function call in program.cs:
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBContext>();
    dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    SeedData.Seed(dbContext);
}

And here is the code to seed the data:
namespace cuahangbanle.DBData.Seed
{
    public static class SeedData
    {
        public static void Seed(DBContext dbContext)
        {
            if (!dbContext.Roles.Any())
            {
                dbContext.Roles.Add(new Role { RoleId = "Admin", RoleName = "Administrator" });
            }
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            if (!dbContext.Accounts.Any())
            {
                dbContext.Accounts.Add(new Account
                {
                    AccountId = "ACC001",
                    Username = "admin",
                    Password = "admin",
                    RoleId = "Admin",
                });
            }
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            if (!dbContext.Suppliers.Any())
            {
                dbContext.Suppliers.AddRange(
                    new Supplier { SupplierId = "SUP001", SupplierName = "Supplier 1", CreatedBy = "ACC001" },
                    new Supplier { SupplierId = "SUP002", SupplierName = "Supplier 2", CreatedBy = "ACC001" }
                );
            }
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            if (!dbContext.Units.Any())
            {
                dbContext.Units.AddRange(
                    new Unit { UnitId = "can", SmallUnit = "can", LargeUnit = "box" },
                    new Unit { UnitId = "package", SmallUnit = "package", LargeUnit = "box" }
                );
            }
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            if (!dbContext.Categories.Any())
            {
                dbContext.Categories.AddRange(
                    new Category { CategoryId = "CAT001", CategoryName = "Category 1", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = "ACC001" },
                    new Category { CategoryId = "CAT002", CategoryName = "Category 2", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = "ACC001" }
                );
            }
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            if (!dbContext.Products.Any())
            {
                try
                {
                    dbContext.Products.AddRange(
                    new Product { ProductId = "PRD001", ProductName = "Coca", CategoryId = "CAT001", SupplierId = "SUP001", SupplierName = "Supplier 1", UnitId = "can", PurchasePrice = 7000, SalePrice = 8000, ProfitMargin = 14.29M, Profit = 1000, Stock = 10 },
                    new Product { ProductId = "PRD002", ProductName = "Hao Hao spicy noodles", CategoryId = "CAT002", SupplierId = "SUP002", SupplierName = "Supplier 2", UnitId = "package", PurchasePrice = 3000, SalePrice = 4000, ProfitMargin = 33.33M, Profit = 1000, Stock = 20 }
                );
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

The error part goes here:
try
{
    dbContext.Products.AddRange(
      new Product { ProductId = "PRD001", ProductName = "Coca", CategoryId = "CAT001", SupplierId = "SUP001", SupplierName = "Supplier 1", UnitId = "can", PurchasePrice = 7000, SalePrice = 8000, ProfitMargin = 14.29M, Profit = 1000, Stock = 10 },
      new Product { ProductId = "PRD002", ProductName = "Hao Hao spicy noodles", CategoryId = "CAT002", SupplierId = "SUP002", SupplierName = "Supplier 2", UnitId = "package", PurchasePrice = 3000, SalePrice = 4000, ProfitMargin = 33.33M, Profit = 1000, Stock = 20 }
    );
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

How should I fix this error?

Could you share definition of your entites? And how they are configured? Any autoincremented keys?

Hi Perfeitor, could you kindly check this sample code and give it a try ?

I do not see Donvitinh entity usage in the original question.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Sorry, I have tried to translate all of my code into English because my original code contained some meaningless unaccented Unicode characters in English, and I was worried that it might cause difficulties for others when reading it. I have edited the question to match the code after translation. I sincerely apologize once again for not paying attention to this earlier.

I do not see why, Unit is duplicated in ChangeTracker. Analyse by yourself in debugger when dbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.ShorView property starts tracking Unit.

@MichałTurczyn My Account table has a foreign key RoleId which references the Id of an entity in the Role table. The Category and Supplier tables have a foreign key CreateBy which references the Id of an entity in the Account table. Finally, the Product table contains three foreign keys which reference entities in the Supplier, Unit, and Category tables, respectively. The issue arises when I try to seed data for the Product table, but the error reported is related to the UnitId in the Unit table.

My data seeding order is: Role > Account > Supplier > Unit > Category > Product. I also don't have any autoincremented keys.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to follow it, and if there are any results, I will update the answer right away.

@JasonPan Your answer has indeed helped my code run without any errors. However, no data is being saved to the database after execution. Any suggestions on this issue?

@JasonPan I forgot to add await before calling the seed data in Program.cs. After adding await, your solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

The correct answer was provided by JasonPan above. Allow me to summarize as follows: change the method from void to async Task, replace all dbContext.SaveChanges() with await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(), add await in front of the data seeding method calls. And finally, add MultipleActiveResultSets=True to your connection string. For example, in my case:
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Data Source =.;Initial Catalog=demostore;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
},

